# JSoup what am I doing wrong with this code?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to extract the text from an h2 tag in HTML through JSoup, but for some reason it's just not working. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

HTML Code:

```
<div id="searchTemplate" class="searchTemplate listLayout so_us_en" >
                <div id="topDynamicContent">
                        <div id="s-result-info-bar" class="a-row a-spacing-base searchUndoAUIHacks"><div id="s-result-info-bar-content" class="a-row"><div class="a-column a-span8 a-spacing-none"><div class="s-first-column">
            <h2 id="s-result-count" class="a-size-base a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small a-text-normal">1-16 of 121 results for <span><span class="a-color-state a-text-bold">&#034;rx 390&#034;</span></span></h2></div>
```

Java Code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_6?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=rx+390&sprefix=rx+390%2Caps%2C166&crid=2MTUBA4KGNY06").get();
        String link= doc.select("div.searchTemplate.listLayout.so_us_en")
                .select("div[id= topDynamicContent]")
                .select("div.a-row.a-spacing-base.searchUndoAUIHacks")
                .select("div.a-row")
                .select("div.a-column.a-span8.a-spacing-none")
                .select("div.s-first-column")
                .select("h2.a-size-base.a-spacing-small.a-spacing-top-small.a-text-normal").first().text();
```

Comment: Please tell the details. What's not working? How? What are you seeing? What are you expecting?

Comment: You code works for me.  The result is `1-16 of 121 results for "rx 390"`.

Comment: That's strange, that part of the code must be right but I'm righting an Android app so something else must not be working. I have no idea what though. Thanks for helping me narrow it down though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you told us in the comments, you are working on an Android app. Therefore there could be a few mistakes (which I experienced myself).

First, did you check, you are running on a seperate thread? Android is a little bit nasty with using Threads for each NetworkThread on the main UI.
For reference see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

You could do something like this in your code:

```
Thread threadNet = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    Document doc;
    try {
      doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_6?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=rx+390&sprefix=rx+390%2Caps%2C166&crid=2MTUBA4KGNY06").get();
      String link= doc.select("div.searchTemplate.listLayout.so_us_en")
                .select("div[id= topDynamicContent]")
                .select("div.a-row.a-spacing-base.searchUndoAUIHacks")
                .select("div.a-row")
                .select("div.a-column.a-span8.a-spacing-none")
                .select("div.s-first-column")
                .select("h2.a-size-base.a-spacing-small.a-spacing-top-small.a-text-normal").first().text();
          System.out.print(link);
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};
threadNet.start();
```

Nonetheless, as mentioned by @saka1029, the code is generally correct and working fine under Windows or Linux systems.

Comment: Yeah, the issue was that I was not running on a separate thread. Thanks for your help! Also, what is the difference between running a thread the way that you wrote above compared to extending AsyncTask within a class? What are the advantages/disadvantages for each one?

Comment: Basically a AsyncTask allows you to update UI components. Which you can't out of the box using a Thread. In order to update the UI inside a Thread you'll need a Handler. An extended explanation is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25848392

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your help.